# Problem installing phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 14 in Goorm IDE Environment

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04, php-7

I've been having troubles installing phpmyadmin on ubuntu 14 LTS delivered by Goorm IDE VM. By default VM come with PHP 7.1.3, ubuntu 14.

I have tried to installing ppa ondrej and nijel repo without success.

One of the issues is that phpmyadmin installed by `apt-get install phpmyadmin` uses a php5.6 installation.

Some other tries php-mbstring and php-ext are not found in repos so I am not able to access to phpmyadmin

Is anyone having these problems?

Comment: So install missing repos too, if they are needed.

Comment: They appeared that they are available anymore. Dont know why. I do not if there is an issue with location, goorm ide seems to be located in Japan. I got an error related to decripted locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that some php related extension packages are not found due to the end of support for Ubuntu 14.04 at last April.

So you need higher version of Ubuntu to install phpmyadmin.

GoormIDE is currently supporting Ubuntu 16.04 with "Blank" stack.

Try to create a container with Blank stack with Ubuntu 16.04 then setup the environment.

To install phpmyadmin with PHP 7.3.6:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update
apt-get install -y mysql-server
service mysql start
apt-get install -y phpmyadmin
```

To run it:

```
service apache2 start
```

To see the application running:

- Enter http(s)://[project_url]/phpmyadmin
- You can check project_url at IDE top menu [Project] - [Running URL and Port]. There will be a URL already registered by default.
- If you don't see any URL registered, register a URL with port 80.

Comment: Thanks Hose. Php version isn´t available with your instructions. After `apt-get update` I needed to execute `apt install php7.3 php7.3-cli php7.3-common` and then every of your instructions were correct. Thank you. I was struggling with this.

Comment: Hello, I just get the default index.php of my project when I add /phpmyadmin/ next to the base url. Do you guys know what's the problem? I have everything installed and configured and I can't see the phpmyadmin